# Why is my iOS app suspended instantly when in background

Tags: ios, iphone, background

I have coded an iOS app that sends data via post to a Web service every second.

I wish to make this app run in the background indefinitely but before that I realized my app is getting suspended instantly when I hit the home button.

From my research on iOS (I'm very new to this), I read that all apps are given at least a few minutes to run in the background. My app already has `location and updates` in Background Modes checked (even though this is not yet implemented).

My question is, is it normal for the app to be suspended immediately when I hit the home button? And if possible how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

You can only run an app in the background it falls in one of the available background modes and. Like you poste you already have the `location and updates` mode there. You will have to track the user location for your app not to be suspended, this has to do with saving the battery charge.

If you mis use the background mode in your app, Apple will reject it. So if you use the background mode `location and updates` and you app is not doing anything the location update it will be rejected.

You should really ask you self whether it is necessary to keep your app running. For example if you just want to finish uploading some data use [Executing Finite-Length Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

User experience is one of the most important features of iOS, thus you should not make you app drain battery when it is not necessary or when it can be done more effeciant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have now added this code to the timer in my app: `CLLocation *locationManager = [[CLLCLLocationManager alloc]  init] ; [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] ;` But my app still gets suspended immediately. Any ideas? (Also, I'm not planning on sending this to the app store)

Comment: That will not work, you need to also start tracking location updates: [`startUpdatingLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation) or [`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges `](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges). Use the later one to save on battery power.

Comment: Isn't startUpdatingLocation the same one I mentioned and used in my first comment? Also, battery consumption is not an issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you setup the delegate? Have you requested the user for accessing their location? Did you set the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in the info.plist? It's not going to that easy ;)

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Start reading the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497)

Comment: Yes, I have listed that in the info.plist. And yes, I keep getting notifications on the screen saying location is turned off in the settings.

Comment: That is because you need to request the user location with [requestAlwaysAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestAlwaysAuthorization), please read the documentation it is all explained in there.